# Yii form validations: comparing password with a field that does not exists in DB

Tags: validation, yii

I am new to Yii framework. I want to validate a password field with the repeated value. I use the following rule:

```
array('password', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password2', 'on'=>'register'),
```

But I receive this error:

```
Property "Users.password2" is not defined
```

How can I fix this problem without creating redundant field *password2* in the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the property in the model without creating it in the db, so add it like so:

```
class Users extends CActiveRecord
    {
        public $password2;
            ...
```